# CSS hover over box to change colour and link

Tags: html, css, hover

Hey guys playing around with CSS. I made a box. Basically what iam trying to figure out is how when the person hovers over the box it will change colour and then link them to anther page in a new tab. Can anyone help me?

Code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="eng" lang="eng">
<head>

<style>
    .border
    {
        height: 150px; 
        width:  150px; 
        border: 1px solid black;  
        text-align:center; 
    }

</style>


</head>
<body>

<div class="border">
    <a href="http://www.1.com/"></a> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the color changing part use the CSS `:hover` pseudo class

```
.border:hover{
   background: green;
}
```

for the link open part use `target="_blank"` in the link tag

```
<a href="http://www.1.com/" target="_blank"></a>
```

That will open the link in a new tab or window depending on the browser settings of the user (which you cannot influence)

Comment: ah this changes the background, how do i just change the border? and thanks for the help

Comment: `.border:hover{border: 1px solid green;}`

Answer (score 1):

Opening links in a specific or new tab cannot be forced. Only opening links in the same window, same frame, custom frame, new frame or a new window can be controlled.

Answer (score 1):

You could add this hover code to the style

```
.border:hover
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

And also wrap the link around the div and use target="_blank"

```
<a href="http://www.1.com/" target="_blank">
<div class="border">

</div>
</a>
```